# Acucobol how to set cell-data of a grid

Tags: grid, set, cobol

I've got a grid called grid-01 in an Acucobol program and I'm trying to change a specific grid cell. I know from the documentation that this should be possible. (See https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/extend-acucobol/925/BKINRHINUI4Z.html)

From that I can tell that I'm supposed to use the SET statement. It also talks about an INQUIRE statement, which I actually did get to work.

This code works to INQUIRE what's in the cell and put it in a variable:

```
inquire grid-01(ws-01-y, 13), cell-data in ws-inquired-cell-data
```

I tried to use the SET statement in the same way:

```
set grid-01(ws-01-y, 13), cell-data to ws-new-cell-data
```

But I get the following errors during compilation:

```
gridprogram.cob, line 4216: GRID-01: Screen name not allowed in this context
gridprogram.cob, line 4216: Undefined data item: GRID-01
gridprogram.cob, line 4216: Undefined data item: CELL-DATA
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried scouring the documentation of the SET statement (https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/extend-acucobol/925/BKRFRFPROC00000001S169.html) but I can't figure out anything specific to grid cell-data in there that might be of any use.

Comment: I have tried to use the MODIFY statement instead of set, which did not give a compile error, but also doesn't appar to do anything. I am confused. I tried `modify grid-01 (ws-01-y, 13), cell-data ws-new-cell-data.` and also the alternative formatting  `modify grid-01 y=ws-01-y x=13, cell-data ws-new-cell-data.`, both of which compile and don't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my issue. While I have 25 data columns set for this grid, only 8 columns are actually supposed to be displayed. Since the cell-data I want to change is in column 13, nothing happens even with the MODIFY statement. However, if I display all these columns, the MODIFY statement works as intended.

The next question is: how can I hide the display columns and still access the data? I thought that was what the data columns were supposed to be for. I can hide them visually by limiting virtual-width, but then I can still use the keyboard to move the cursor outside of the virtual boundary.

I am further confused about how I can inquire into the column 13 when it is not displayed, yet not modify it.